# Does the density of matter increase as we approach the big bang?

Tags: astrophysics, big-bang, metric-tensor

I am interested in knowing whether it is clear (undisputed) that the density of matter/energy increases as we approach the time of the big bang?

Does this follow from the FLRW metric?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What was the density of the universe when it was only the size of our solar system?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126553/)

Comment: What's your definition of "undisputed"? Are there people who will scream "No, it just ain't so!"? Yes. Do these people have evidence? No.

Comment: Thanks John, this question didn't come up when I was typing it. I will check it out.

Comment: John Rennie's answer above answers my question, thanks!