# Numerical solution for Friedmann equations

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, computational-physics

My problem today is to solve the Friedmann equations, for those who aren't familiar with them, here they are (in my specific case):

$$ \left ( \frac{\dot{a}}{a^2} \right )^2 = \frac{\rho_1}{a^4} - \frac{\rho_2}{a^6} $$

So, my idea for solving this is to discretise in time, namely, write:
$$ \dot{a} = \pm \sqrt{\rho_1 - \frac{\rho_2}{a^2} }$$
And then 
$$ \dot{a} = \frac{a_{i+1} - a_{i}}{dt}$$
Now, I want to start with $\dot{a} < 0$, and make it "bounce". Namely, if you solve these equations analytically, you get:
$$ a(t) = \sqrt{\rho_1 t^2 + \frac{\rho_2}{\rho_1}} $$
Meaning that $a(t)$ has a minimum value, at $t = 0$. However, using time discretisation one gets( in the phase when $\dot{a}<0$
$$ a_{i+1} = a_i - dt \sqrt{\rho_1 - \frac{\rho_2}{a_i^2} }$$
Which at some point becomes complex.

This procedure has obviously some flaws, how can I correct it? I would like to write an algorithm that solves numerically using some sort of time discretisation, since I later will need to implement for a time variable $\rho_2(t)$. The algorithm must reproduce the analytical solution, with the feature that, once we have reached the minimum value for $a(t)$, it stops decreasing and starts increasing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: You need an implicit differential equation solver.

Comment: Pulsar's answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/equation-for-hubble-value-as-a-function-of-time) may be useful. See also [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point) and [How does the Hubble parameter change with the age of the universe?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136056/how-does-the-hubble-parameter-change-with-the-age-of-the-universe), which use Pulsar's results to calculate $a(t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearranging your first equation you get
$$\dot{a}^2 = \rho_1 - \frac{\rho_2}{a^2}$$
In this case you need only to give an initial condition $a(0)>\sqrt{\rho_2/\rho_1}$.

If you want to reach the bounce, integrate with a negative velocity forward in time (or vice versa), i.e. $\dot{a}=-\sqrt{\rho_1 -\rho_2/a^2}, \Delta t > 0$. Once you reach the bounce $a^2=\rho_2/\rho_1$ (or $\dot{a}=0$), switch the sign of the  velocity so that your universe grows instead of shrinking. (Beware of NaNs from square-rooting a negative number!)

Note that the solution is not uniquely determined at the very point of the bounce - there are two possible branches, a real and a complex one, corresponding to negative and positive velocity. We choose the real one because of physical reasons. (See [Picard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Intuitive_understanding_of_the_theorem) on existence and uniqueness of first order ODEs.)

Comment: No, the equation and the solutions are correct. The solution to your equation is also a bounce, but given by logarithm.. But thanks anyway, i'll try the change of sign..

Comment: @MrFermiMr Yes, sorry, I misread your first equation which is usually given in terms of $\dot{a}^2/a^2$ rather than $\dot{a}^2/a^4$ on the left hand side. Corrected.

Comment: Yes, it's written in conformal time $dt = a(t') \; dt'$..  Actually i think that's precisely what happens: the solution goes and then, precisely at $a = \sqrt{\rho_1/\rho_2}$ the solution becomes complex. It is just a matter of telling mathematica to change sign when the complex part becomes non zero, and i should be good.