# About the ratio of the density of dark energy at the time of cosmic microwave background emission to the current density of dark energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, astronomy

In a question, I am given the current densities of dark energy, dark matter and normal matter and am asked to find the ratio of density of dark energy at the time of CMB and now.

The answer is 1. Is this a simple calculation or is it something we are expected to know?

Comment: Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our [meta site](//meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5958) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming dark energy is a cosmological constant and not quintessence or something more complicated, it is a constant and does not change as the universe expands. Well, if it changed it would be a cosmological *variable* not a *constant*!

For more on this type of calculation you should read Pulsar's answer to [Equation for Hubble Value as a function of time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/equation-for-hubble-value-as-a-function-of-time/92515) as this describes the principles involved.